# Timespan in C# converting to int? Somehow?

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm trying to use the Timespan class to create a start time and a stop time, get the difference and ultimately dividing and multiplying the result against another number.

The problem is getting into something I can work with.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what it is you're trying to achieve in more detail.  I've posted an answer which hopefully assists you, but if what you're trying to do can not be done with a TimeSpan my answer won't help much.

Comment: As an aside, if you're creating a TimeSpan by recording two separate DateTime values and taking the difference, I recommend using DateTime.UtcNow in place of DateTime.Now.  The latter exhibits a nasty behavior (if you're relying on the time stamps in any critical way) when transitioning to Daylight Savings Time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to measure code running time, the [stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

The TimeSpan class has a number of members which might be able to assist, for instance TotalSeconds, TotalMinutes, TotalHours etc.

If you want to know the number of operations per second, divide the number of operations by the TotalSeconds member of the TimeSpan object.

Comment: I'm attempting to use it to move a 3D model between two Vector3 points in 3-space. I need to know the time displacement to do so.
The Formula I am using is 
  
position = start location + ((time displacement / total time) * (end location - start location))

Perhaps Timespan is not the answer?

Comment: it might still be - you just need to decide on your unit.

If time is measured in Seconds then use TotalSeconds.

If you are using Frames as your unit of measure then TimeSpan won't help (short of calculating Frames per Second).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need milliseconds. I've fooling around with this for an hour
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan();
//Some time has passed I promise!! =)
TimeSpan stop = new TimeSpan();

int time1 = start.Milliseconds;
int time2 = stop.Milliseconds;
int currTime = time2 - time1;
Console.WriteLine(currTime + " " + time1.ToString() + " " + time2.ToString());

This did not seem to work either, I get 0 for all values.

Comment: Sorry bout that, I did format the code before posting, got bunched up =(

Comment: @Bryan When you create a TimeSpan with new you get the same as `TimeSpan.Zero`. Then you subtract zero from zero which is, obviously,  zero. Your code would work if you took the current time with `DateTime.UtcNow`. However, if this is the use you will be doing, use the `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: @Bryan: Also, TimeSpan.Milliseconds is not the same as TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds. Say, the timespan is 42.983 seconds. Milliseconds is 983, while TotalMilliseconds is 42983.

Comment: +1: And considering your usage, most physics calculations use meters/second so it's probably easiest to use TotalSeconds.